# Hierarchical clustering output 99% belongs to a cluster group

Tags: clustering, normalization, hierarchical-clustering

I've just done a clustering analysis using hierarchical clustering analysis in Python but the result is not what I expect. Most of them (483/485) belongs to group 1 and the rest to group 0. Is there anything wrong that I did in the code or this is on of the downside of this analysis?

I'm using a dataset consists of 485 data with only two variables (sales count and sales amount) whose value is very fluctuated with some outliers in both variables.

Before conducting the analysis, I used this code to normalize the data

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
x_std = StandardScaler().fit_transform(x)
x_std
```

After that I did the analysis and here's the dendogram and the code I used

[image: Analysis Dendogram]

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))  
plt.title("Dendrograms")  
dend = shc.dendrogram(shc.linkage(x_std, method='ward'))
plt.axhline(y=6, color='r', linestyle='--')
```

```
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
cluster = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=2, affinity='euclidean', linkage='ward')  
partner_cluster = cluster.fit_predict(x_std)
partner_cluster
```

Is there anything that I did wrong, or is there any other technique that I could use? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify why you think something is wrong. If the data are tightly related except for a few, this is normal and should be understood as revealing something useful.

Comment: Hi @AryaMcCarthy, I should clarify that maybe there's nothing wrong here, but I expected that I have various cluster for each individual, yet I got the result that's pretty homogenous.